# No suitable conversion function from [class name] to [class name]*

Tags: c++-cli

I am new to c++/cli, the situation I faced is that:
the project I am doing needs to use an external dll, in my functions I need to use classes A, B and C which are from this dll, I put them in my .h file, the .h file looking like:

```
#include library I use
    public ref class MyClass
    {
    public:
            MyClass();
            ~MyClass();
            otherfuc();
    private:
            A *a;
            B *b;
            C *c;
    }
```

My .cpp file looking like:

```
MyClass::MyClass() 
{
    a = new A();
    b = new B(*a);
    c = b->func();   //error happened
}
MyClass::otherfunc()
{
    c->func_c()
}
```

Class A, B, C are unmanaged class, so I only have one way to declare them in managed class, just like I do in the header file. In class B, it has a function which is called func, this function return class type C, I tried c = &b->func(), in this way, it will throw AccessViolationException, if I tried c = b->func, then the error is function call missing argument. What should I do, please help!!!

Comment: b->func() is returning a temporary object instance. You are storing the address of that in MyClass::c. When the constructor exits the temporary is destroyed and MyClass::c contains an invalid address. Later you call otherfunc() and the invalid address in 'c' is used causing an access violation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It helps for me to understand. To this specific problem, do you know is there any way I could do to implement it? I really appreciate.@tukra

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written my guess is that B::func() is declared to return a C instance as a temporary:

```
class B {
public:
    C func();
};
```

Allocate an instance of C as a copy of temporary:

```
class A {
};

class C {
public:
    C(int _i) : i(_i) {}
    int func_c() { return i; }

    int i;
};

class B {
public:
    B(A & a) {}
    C func() { return C(5); }
};

public ref class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    int otherfunc();
private:
    A *a;
    B *b;
    C *c;
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    a = new A();
    b = new B(*a);
    c = new C(b->func());
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;
}

int MyClass::otherfunc()
{
    return c->func_c();
}

void f() {
    MyClass^ mc = gcnew MyClass();
    int i = mc->otherfunc();
}
```

This assumes C is copyable (or moveable) and that copying it make sense for what you are doing.

Comment: C is a unmanaged class, I do not think I can declare it in your way.@tukra

Comment: Ha, of course. I fixed the example to be complete working code.